# How do you connect webkit devtools from IDE?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, node-webkit

*Short explanation*:

I have a webpage in chrome browser which have **no url** and have some sources which **are acessible only by chrome devtools**.

Devtools are started with remote debugging flag, which allows me type localhost:9222 in browser and see devtools there with all sources to debug.

*Details*:

I'm starting a node-webkit app, which is, in a short words, is a node.js script along with my app scripts embedded into a webpage, which is displayed by standalone webkit engine.

So it's basically normal webpage in chrome but without url.

And then I want to debug scripts with remote debugger in IDEA (or Eclipse). This page have no url, but it have chrome developer tools which can be enabled for remote debug.

*Question*:

I want to use standart IDE like eclipse/IDEA instead of devtools to debug code. How do i connect devtools remote debug to IDE?